# chef knife: run_list with multiple roles in ec2 server create command

Tags: amazon-ec2, command-line-interface, chef

I'm using chef's knife to create EC2 servers (and thus new nodes). I can get it to start with a given single role correctly, but I can't get the command line argument right for multiple roles in the node's run_list. How do I specify multiple roles for the newly created node in the command line (without editing the node JSON in an editor as shown [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/233106/chef-node-attribute-how-to-manage-them-locally-versioned-and-then-upload-them))?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I posted this question on the [Opscode support site](http://help.opscode.com/) and received a very prompt response. Quoting from the [Opscode support thread](http://help.opscode.com/discussions/questions/304-chef-knife-run_list-with-multiple-roles-in-ec2-server-create-command):

for chef 0.9.x:

```
knife ec2 server create ... 'role[foo]' 'role[bar]' 'role[baz]'
```

for chef 0.10.x:

```
knife ec2 server create ... -r 'role[foo], role[bar], role[baz]'
```

Works great, thanks Stephen!